# Как удалить данные из связующей таблицы в sequelize

Tags: javascript

У меня есть 2 таблицы Reader и Book. Они связаны отношением многие ко многим через таблицу ReaderBooks. В этой таблице у меня показаны какие книги выданы читателям. У читателя может быть много книг. Так вот мне надо вернуть книгу, то есть удалить из базы данных строку.
Например у idReader = 1 выданы книги idBook = 1,2. Я передаю пост запрос с id книги и пользователя которые хочу удалить, и затем данные удаляются из таблицы ReaderBooks. Как это сделать?
Попытался так но работает некорректно.

```
const Book = sequelize.define('Book', {
    id: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
    title: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false},
    author: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false},
    vendorCode: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false},
    year: {type: DataTypes.DATEONLY, allowNull: false},
    numberOfCopies: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER}
});

const Reader = sequelize.define('Reader', {
    id: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
    fullName: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false},
    birth: {type: DataTypes.DATEONLY, allowNull: false}
});

const ReaderBook = sequelize.define('ReaderBook', {
});

Reader.belongsToMany(Book, {through: 'ReaderBook'});
Book.belongsToMany(Reader, {through: 'ReaderBook'});

module.exports = {Book, Reader, ReaderBook};
```

мой метод:

```
async returnBook(req, res) {
        try {
            const {idReader, idBook} = req.body;
            const book = await Book.findByPk(idBook);
            const reader = await Reader.findByPk(idReader);
            if (!reader || !book) {
                return res.status(400).json({message: 'Reader or Book does not exist'});
            }
            await reader.removeBook({
                include: {
                    model: Book,
                    where: {
                        id: idBook
                    }
                },
                where: {
                    id: idReader
                }
            });
            return res.json("Test");
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
            return res.status(400).json({message: 'Error returning a book to a reader'});
        }
    };
```